# Способ работы с большими данными android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, хранение-данных

Я пишу на kotlin под android английский словарь. У меня есть большая база слов (`50 000`, примерно). Данные в формате json, но можно и в другой перебросить.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, структуру данных (способ хранения данных) для android, чтобы я имел возможность при запуске приложения загружать список слов в `RecyclerView` и при этом делать это достаточно быстро (хотя бы до 10 секунд).

Я пробовал использовать Json, но при попытке загрузки файла приложение падает с `OutOfMemory`. Если использовать БД (`Sqlite`), то загрузка работает слишком долго.

Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Я в `kotlin` если не новичок, то от него ушёл не далеко, так что тапками сильно не кидайтесь.

P.P.S. Код для Sqlite (брал [отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/readydb.php)):

```kotlin
class DataBaseWordsHelper(context: Context) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1) {
    private var myDataBase: SQLiteDatabase? = null
    private val mContext: Context

    fun createDataBase() {
        val dbExist = checkDataBase()
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.readableDatabase
            copyDataBase()
        }
    }

    private fun checkDataBase(): Boolean {
        var checkDB: SQLiteDatabase? = null
        try {
            val myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)
        } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
            
        }
        checkDB?.close()
        return checkDB != null
    }


    private fun copyDataBase() {
        val myInput: InputStream = mContext.assets.open(DB_NAME)

        val outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME

        val myOutput: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(outFileName)

        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var length: Int
        while (myInput.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }


        myOutput.flush()
        myOutput.close()
        myInput.close()
    }

    fun openDataBase() {
        val myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)
    }

    @Synchronized
    override fun close() {
        if (myDataBase != null) myDataBase!!.close()
        super.close()
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {}
    override fun onUpgrade(
        db: SQLiteDatabase,
        oldVersion: Int,
        newVersion: Int,
    ) {
    }

    fun getWords(): List<Word>? {
        // эта функция занимает много времени

        openDataBase()

        val res = mutableListOf<Word>()
        val curWords = myDataBase?.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM words", null) ?: return null

        for (i in 0 until curWords.count) {
            curWords.moveToPosition(i)

            val mns = mutableListOf<Meaning>()

            val curMeanings = myDataBase?.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM meanings WHERE WordId = ?", arrayOf(curWords.getInt(0).toString())) ?: return null

            for (j in 0 until curMeanings.count) {
                curMeanings.moveToPosition(j)

                val exs = mutableListOf<String>()

                val curExamples = myDataBase?.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM examples WHERE MeaningId = ?", arrayOf(curMeanings.getInt(0).toString())) ?: return null

                for (k in 0 until curExamples.count) {

                    curExamples.moveToPosition(k)

                    exs.add(curExamples.getString(2))
                }

                curExamples.close()

                val m = Meaning(
                    curMeanings.getString(2),
                    curMeanings.getString(3),
                    curMeanings.getString(4),
                    curMeanings.getString(5),
                    curMeanings.getString(6),
                    exs
                )

                mns.add(m)
            }

            curMeanings.close()

            val w = Word(
                curWords.getString(1),
                curWords.getString(2),
                curWords.getString(3),
                curWords.getString(4),
                mns
            )
            res.add(w)
        }

        curWords.close()
        close()

        return res
    }

    companion object {
        private const val DB_PATH = "/data/data/Имя_моего_пакета/databases/"
        private const val DB_NAME = "words.db"
    }

    init {
        mContext = context
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте SQLite, лучше способа хранить структурированные данные на устройствах имхо пока не придумано. Напишите в вопросе подробнее, какая была проблема с SQLite, куда вы ее "грузили"? На что предположительно тратилось время? В конце концов, SQLite можно заполнить [заранее](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate) и встроить в ваше приложение, тогда все будет работать очень быстро.

Comment: Чтобы вставлять данные в RecyclerView, не нужно сразу читать все данные. В SQLite можно с помощью курсоров получать данные по мере необходимости (по ходу скролла в ресайклере). Кроме этого, можно взять [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) и посмотреть на стандартную библиотеку для [пагинации](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging).

Comment: Добавил код, как вы и просили. Возможно, буду двигаться в сторону Room. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сразу получить все данные из БД, поместить их в переменные и после вывести их. Поэтому у вас происходит долгое ожидание/обработка данных.

В адаптер `RecyclerView` можно предавать `Cursor`, тогда элементы данных будут запрашиваться из БД по мере прокрутки списка.

Пример адаптера для работы с БД на `JAVA` ( на `Kotlin` переписывайте сами):

```
public class RVExample extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVExample.ViewHolder> {
    Cursor mCursor;
    RVExample(Cursor cursor){
        mCursor=cursor;
    }

    //Кол-во элементов списка получаем из курсора
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Здесь вместо my_element_list - прописываем свою разметку для элемента списка
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_element_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RVExample.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Перебираем элементы списка
        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        //подставляем данные в список, смотри код ниже
        holder.bindCursor(mCursor);
    }

    //Здесь работаете с заполнение карточки списка, например в разметке my_element_list два TextView
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView text1,text2;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text1=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            text2=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        }
        //Здесь присваиваете данные текстовым элементам значением колонок из БД.
        private void bindCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            text1.setText(cursor.getString(0));
            text2.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

В классе где вы объявляете RV и подключаете адаптер и передаете ему данные:

```
RVExample mAdapter = new RVExample( db.rawQuery('SQL запрос', null));
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо большое!

Comment: С точки зрения дизайна, я бы рекомендовал в конструктор передавать `SQLiteDatabase`, а не `Cursor`. Адаптер ведь не умеет работать с любым курсором, а ожидает какую-то определенную структуру данных. Поэтому и SQL-запрос должен быть определен в адаптере.